# Extracting string before a fixed character position

Tags: r, substring

Its fairly simple question, I tried multiple combinations however I am not getting to what I want to achieve. 
I have a columns which has statement separate by "-". I want to extract the words before the fourth instance of "-" from 
the month of April.

I am using this code which trims the part before the 4th "-" and it returns anything left after that.

```
data$newCol1 <- NA 
data$newCol1 <- ifelse(data$date >= as.Date("2019-04-01"), sub(".?-.?-.?-.?-", "", data$Email), ifelse(data$date <= as.Date("2019-03-31"),data$Email,data$newCol1))
```

However I want to extract the portion before the 4th "-" for eg if this my string "19Q1-XYZ-JA-All-OutR-random-key-March" I want only 19Q1-XYZ-JA-All instead of having OutR-random-key-March which is what i get currently

This is my dataset

```
Email                                           date
18Q4-ABC-SEA-CO-TM                              1/8/2019
19Q1-DEF-ABJPODTSST                             1/16/2019
19Q1-ABC-CMJ                                    2/8/2019
19Q1-APC-CORP                                   4/9/2019
19Q1-XYZ-ALP-SEA-MOO  ABc_1                     5/13/2019
19Q1-WXY-All-SF- Coral 01_24                    1/27/2019
19Q1-XYZ-All-SF-Tokyo SF Event 03_14 FINAL Send 3/14/2019
19Q1-XYZ-CN-All-cra-foo world-2901              1/30/2019
19Q1-XYZ-CN-All-get-foo world-2901              1/31/2019
19Q1-XYZ-CN-All-opc-foo world-2901              7/31/2019
19Q1-XYX-FI-AC-DEC-kites                        1/21/2019
19Q1-XYZ-JA-All-OutR-random-key-March           7/19/2019
19Q1-XYZ-JA-All-OutR-random-key-March           6/19/2019
19Q1-XYZ-JA-SF-OutR-RFC_ABS-key-March           3/29/2019
19Q1-XYZ-unavailable-random-key-balaji          4/20/2019
```

Comment: It would be great if you have sshowed the expected output for cross comparison

Comment: hi, I have in the question...What I am looking to have in the new column is part that I am extracting out i.e, "19Q1-XYZ-JA-All" here for the entry 7/19/2019

Comment: okay, then please check the solution I posted below

Answer (score 0):

An option is to to match 3 sets of characters that are not a `-` followed by `-` and the next set of characters that are not a `-` (`[^-]+`), capture as a group and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of that captured group

```
data$date <- as.Date(data$date, "%m/%d/%Y")
data$newCol1 <- NA 
data$newCol1 <- ifelse(data$date >= as.Date("2019-04-01"), 
    sub("^(([^-]+-){3}[^-]+)-.*", "\\1", data$Email),
   ifelse(data$date <= as.Date("2019-03-31"),data$Email,data$newCol1))
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(Email = c("18Q4-ABC-SEA-CO-TM", "19Q1-DEF-ABJPODTSST", 
"19Q1-ABC-CMJ", "19Q1-APC-CORP", "19Q1-XYZ-ALP-SEA-MOO  ABc_1", 
"19Q1-WXY-All-SF- Coral 01_24", "19Q1-XYZ-All-SF-Tokyo SF Event 03_14 FINAL Send", 
"19Q1-XYZ-CN-All-cra-foo world-2901", "19Q1-XYZ-CN-All-get-foo world-2901", 
"19Q1-XYZ-CN-All-opc-foo world-2901", "19Q1-XYX-FI-AC-DEC-kites", 
"19Q1-XYZ-JA-All-OutR-random-key-March", "19Q1-XYZ-JA-All-OutR-random-key-March", 
"19Q1-XYZ-JA-SF-OutR-RFC_ABS-key-March", "19Q1-XYZ-unavailable-random-key-balaji"
), date = c("1/8/2019", "1/16/2019", "2/8/2019", "4/9/2019", 
"5/13/2019", "1/27/2019", "3/14/2019", "1/30/2019", "1/31/2019", 
"7/31/2019", "1/21/2019", "7/19/2019", "6/19/2019", "3/29/2019", 
"4/20/2019")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to use `?gregexpr` function to get the position of all `-` and then extract the string based on its position:

I use the data created by @akrun

```
result <- sapply(data$Email, function(x)substr(x, 1, gregexpr("-",x)[[1]][4]-1))

result
```

This will simply generate `NA` value since some string only has 3 "-", you can simply modify the code using `if` condition to filter them.

Comment: hi, I just wanted to know in this syntax does grepexpr identifies the position of "-" cause if that's the case, I was thinking of modifying my code to check the date and position of "-" and perform extraction thus. like for the 3 "-" I'll copy the string as is but for 4 "-" I'll extract the substring.